# C#: Excel export doesn't show correctly for Myanmar Font data

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am trying to get datatable data as a CSV file. But the data with Myanmar font doesn't show correctly in excel. It is showing as the following character.

"á€œá€™á€ºá€¸ áá‚  á€œá€±á€¸á€•á€¯á€¶á€á€•á€¯á€¶  á€™á€¼á€­á€¯á€·"
I attached my code.

```
DataTable dt = ToDataTable(objList);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);

        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
           
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }
        string folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Files") + "/Files/Export/";
        File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "Export.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "Export.csv", sb.ToString());
```

With

```
File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "Export.csv", sb.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);
```

According to
[https://www.unicode.org/faq/myanmar.html#:~:text=A%3A%20The%20Myanmar%20script%20was,extended%20the%20script%20in%202009](https://www.unicode.org/faq/myanmar.html#:%7E:text=A%3A%20The%20Myanmar%20script%20was,extended%20the%20script%20in%202009).

> The Myanmar script was added to the Unicode Standard in Version 3.0 (September, 1999). Version 5.2 significantly extended the script in 2009